# Finding files that match regex

Tags: regex, shell

So, I'm trying to write a shell script that finds all the files in the current directory that match a fixed regex pattern(in basic regex) given as an argument to my script.

What I came up with is:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex "\.\/"$1""
```

I have those ./ in the beginning because the find command finds me the files and prints them in ./files format.

The command works if I give the script the argument a.* but if I try to give it something like [0-9]\{2\}[a-zA-Z]* to find me all the files starting with 2 digits, followed by letters, nothing happens and I'm figuring out that it has something to do with escaping special characters but I can't seem to understand why and how to do it properly...

Comment: What do you think `$1` is doing here?

Comment: Presumably this line is within a script or function somewhere. Are you quoting the argument when you pass it? `your_func '[0-9]\{2\}[a-zA-Z]*'`

Comment: I'm not quoting the argument, but it doesn't seem to work even if I pass it like that and um, $1 is replaced with the argument but I'm not quoting it right in the script I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* quote the argument you're passing, otherwise it may be glob-expanded by the shell before being passed. Also, you will lose the `\` as the shell will expand things like `\{` to just `{`.

You should also quote your argument `$1` like this:

```
find_regex() {
    find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex "\./$1"
}

# usage: find_regex '[0-9]\{2\}[a-zA-Z]*'
```

This matches a literal `.`, followed by a `/`, followed by the argument passed to the function. The way you had it in the question meant that the `$1` was outside of double quotes, so you would be subject to glob-expansion and losing slashes for the second time.

Comment: Is the `{}` present in all versions of find? Because my test case didn't seem to 'like' it. In any escaping pattern.

Comment: The `-regex` switch is only supported in some versions and according to the [GNU find docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), POSIX basic regular expressions are supported. So `\{N\}` should be understood to mean `N` occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is because your filenames *don't* start with numbers.

Try running:

```
 find ./ -depth 1
```

And look at the paths you get. In particular in the `find` manpage, note:

> This is a match on the whole path, not a search

So you should assume implicit `^` and `$` anchors.

You probably want something like:

```
find ./ -depth 1 -regex "\./[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z]*"
```

I didn't get any joy with `{}` as quantifiers, so have opted for the simpler answer that works. This may be down to different versions of `find`.

Alternatively I might suggest getting perl out, especially as you're only traversing one level:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", grep {m/^\d{2}/} glob ( "*" ) '
```

This uses the subtley different perl grep, which does it match wise on just the filename (expanded from `*`).

Or you can add a path:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", grep {m,/\d{2},} glob ( "./*" )'
```